# How to tell ordinary spam from some abusing my mail?

Tags: spam, email-spoofing

From time to time I glance through my spam folder to gauge how the filters are working, and if they're catching any "ham." Most of the spam is really obvious, but I'm getting a few which made me wonder if somebody is using my email (presumably in systems which do not require double-opt-in).

Some of the mails simply make no sense as spam, but I guess they might be tests if my mailbox bounces the request or not.

Are there relatively pain-free ways to find out if that is the case? In a couple of weeks the new EU General Data Protection Regulation comes into force and I could just ask companies what they have on me, but that would be a lot of work for me and for them, and fruitless if the sender was forged.

---

Re the comment, I hestiated to do give examples because it might "smear" a perfectly legitimate service.

> > Received: from r157.p23.neolane.net ([66.117.16.157]) by [...]
> >     From: "Heathrow Airport" 
> >     Subject: Welcome to Heathrow Wi-Fi - let us help you explore
> >     To: [...]

Comment: An example email would be helpful.

Comment: @NeilSmithline, done.

Answer (score 1):

If they are sites, where you are allowed to log in, you could try resetting your password. That being said, there is little reason to do that. It could provide the site with additional information about you and it could allow some amount of phishing, so you need to be careful with this.

One danger I can think of is the site forwarding you a link/code for a different site and then using this code to confirm them as the owner of the email.

If the site does not have such functionality, then I can't see any easy way to do this.